# MapboxDraw & Next.js "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAll')"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, mapbox

I'm getting this Error when trying to access an object which is defined everywhere else in the code but is undefined when rendering JSX. I am able to access the object's properties within the callback functions, and within the body of the page, for instance within the `onCreate` callback function, and within the Home page.

I will provide the necessary files below.

`Next.js ^13.2.4`

```js
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAll')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
src/pages/index.tsx (36:15) @ getAll

  34 | <SidePanel>
  35 |   {draw &&
> 36 |     draw.getAll().features.map((v, i) => {
     |         ^
  37 |       <div key={i}>{v.id}</div>;
  38 |     })}
  39 | </SidePanel>
```

Here is the full Next.js page.

```js
import { type NextPage } from "next";
import { useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import Map, { MapRef } from "react-map-gl";
import MapboxDraw, {
  DrawCreateEvent,
  DrawDeleteEvent,
  DrawUpdateEvent,
} from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw";
import DrawControl from "~/components/controls/DrawControl";
import SidePanel from "~/components/sidepanel/SidePanel";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef<MapRef>(null);
  const [viewState, setViewState] = useState({
    longitude: *******,
    latitude: *******,
    zoom: 13,
  });
  const draw = new MapboxDraw();

  const onCreate = useCallback((evt: DrawCreateEvent) => {
    // this works
    console.log(draw.getAll());
  }, []);

  const onUpdate = useCallback((evt: DrawUpdateEvent) => {}, []);

  const onDelete = useCallback((evt: DrawDeleteEvent) => {}, []);

  const onMapLoad = useCallback(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <>
      <SidePanel>
        {draw &&
          draw.getAll().features.map((v, i) => {
            <div key={i}>{v.id}</div>;
          })}
      </SidePanel>
      <Map
        {...viewState}
        ref={mapRef}
        onLoad={onMapLoad}
        onMove={(evt) => {
          setViewState(evt.viewState);
        }}
        mapboxAccessToken="*******"
        style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
        mapStyle="*******"
      >
        <DrawControl
          drawInstance={draw}
          defaultMode="simple_select"
          onCreate={onCreate}
          onUpdate={onUpdate}
          onDelete={onDelete}
        />
      </Map>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```